# JS Canvas not drawing line

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

i'm starting to learn JSCanvas and i'm having trouble getting the line to even show.
here is the script i'm using. Am i missing anything?

```html
<body>
        This is just a test
    <br></br>
    <canvas id = "FirstCanvas" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;">

    </canvas>
</body>

<script>
    var c =
    document.getElementById("FirstCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getcontext("2d");
    ctx.moveto(0,0);
    ctx.lineto (200,100);
    ctx.stroke();
</script>

<style>
    #FirstCanvas{
        background-color: aquamarine;
    }
</style>
```

all i get is the picture i attached.

I have tried removing the style sections, re-ordering the section etc and nothing is making the line appear.

Comment: Look at the browser developer tools console and see the error message. It'll tell you exactly what's wrong: `"TypeError: c.getcontext is not a function"`. Then you can [look at the docs for the function you're trying to call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) and see what the problem is. Based on the docs, we see the function is really `getContext`, with a capital C.

Comment: Why do you i gore errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, case matters. That is why the code above doesn't work. Take a look at the `getcontext`, `moveto`, `lineto` methods, all these should be written in camelCase, i.e. `getContext`, `moveTo`, `lineTo` :)

Comment: Thank you. I can’t believe I I we looked that.